# Code Block Formatting indentation

Tags: bug, status-norepro

In the Edit window there are obviously spaces in [this question](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/60244/coding-using-arduino-2-74hc595-and-2-rgbled-problems-with-shifting-out-databas). Why are the indentations ignored in the rendering of the code block?

Comment: never mind, somehow it fixed itself